# Sass: module loop when using @use and @forward

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass

In my `style.scss` I am loading a scss file by using:

```
@use "bootstrap/functions";
```

Somewhat later in the `style.scss` I load another scss file called `_variables.scss`. In this file I also want to use the functions file, for example by doing:

```
$link-color:                functions.theme-color("primary") !default;
@include functions.assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
SassError: Module loop: this module is already being loaded.
   ┌──> src/assets/scss/bootstrap/_variables.scss
4  │ @forward "functions";
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ new load
   ╵
   ┌──> src/assets/scss/style.scss
22 │ @use "bootstrap/functions";
   │ ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ original load
   ╵
```

I tried loading it with `@use` and `@forward`, I also tried not loading it to see if it can find it in the current context, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Webpack with the `sass-loader` that uses `dart-sass`.

Comment: Have you used @import ?

Comment: I changed everything back to import. Works again now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently having the same issue, due to `@import` being depreciated in October 2022.

This is because you're effectively loading bootstrap/functions into your `style.scss` twice, once as itself, and once within `_variables.scss`.

Because `@use` isn't global, like `@import` is, it seems to automatically reject any duplications, throwing an error rather than ignoring the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reason you're having this issue is that you're trying to load two files that depend on each other; `_functions.scss` & `_variables.scss` and this just isn't possible. To load a file, it must be fully executed and this isn't possible when both are depending on each other. There can only be one dependent between two files.

A similar [issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2774) was raised on the sass GitHub repo by [jacobScripts](https://github.com/jacobScripts).